# Google Colab Pro+ Disconnects and Stops Executing, and Only Allows One Session

Tags: google-colaboratory

My notebook disconnects randomly and stops executing. It's supposed to send files to Drive but stops and won't reconnect.

Also, as of today it's only allowing me one session at a time. I thought the limit was more?

I've checked and I'm still active on the Pro+ plan, which I only paid for about a week ago.

This affects all of my notebooks as well as new copies.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to handle with Google support.

Comment: Their support is literally a link to post on stackexchange.

https://i.imgur.com/M55b38a.png

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with a similar issue and [answered a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607177/google-colab-pro-freezes-after-clo/72410348#72410348). I reproduce the gist of the answer below:

> The best solution I've been able to come up with (which works inconsistently, but seems to help a lot more that otherwise) is to prevent my screen from locking. Let me explain.

> I run Colab Pro+ on a Macbook laptop, and the battery-saving settings are ordinarily such that the screen locks when the laptop is idle for 5 mins. I noticed that for some reason Colab was much more likely to freeze and disconnect if I was away from the laptop than if I were working on it for hours as it ran (presumably because the screed doesn't lock when I'm working). So to superficially mimic this, I changed my settings to never lock the screen. And I then realized that with these settings Colab would freeze and disconnect much less frequently, and I could successfully let it run overnight and check it in the morning. [Edit: let me clarify that I have not tried this while closing the browser. So I can attest to the efficacy of my method if you leave the browser open].

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue, but I think it's a bug rather than resource usage limit since I was able to connect to another TPU session even though I couldn't get a GPU.
Which leads to my suggestion, if you need additional sessions, try to connect to a TPU session in addition to a GPU session. (Hopefully your code is easily implemented on TPU!)