# Only one active GPU session with High-RAM Usage (Colab Pro+)

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Been using Google Colab for some time now, but recently i upgraded to Pro+ thinking it would give me the possibility to open more sessions simultaniously. I was wrong despite what the description about the upgrade stated in the Google Colab Pro+.
So i'm asking if anyone knows if it's normal or should i report it as a 'bug'?
If anyone can help me out, it would be most welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I responded to a similar post here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132974/16879039.
TLDR I think its a bug. If you need more resources immediately, I had luck by choosing a TPU session instead of GPU (No guarantees and might be difficult to convert your code depending on what you're doing).

Comment: I actually tried GPU and TPU sessions, both didn't work. It gave me only the possibility to connect to a non-accelerated runtime (meaning: standard RAM and neither GPU nor TPU)