# Google Colab Pro+ freezes after clo

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I got a Colab Pro+ because I wanted to use the background execution option.
I enabled the background execution and GPU type and started my code.
My code is a simple CNN on Tiny ImageNet, which requires several hours of training on a GPU.

I closed the browser, and after one-two hours, I returned, and everything was frozen!

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens to me as well and the best solution I've been able to come up with (which works inconsistently, but seems to help a lot more that otherwise) is to prevent my screen from locking. Let me explain.

I run Colab Pro+ on a Macbook laptop, and the battery-saving settings are ordinarily such that the screen locks when the laptop is idle for 5 mins, the lockscreen comes up. I noticed that for some reason Colab was much more likely to freeze and disconnect if I was away from the laptop than if I were working on it for hours as it ran, so to superficially mimic this, I changed my settings to never lock the screen. And I then I realized that with these settings Colab would freeze and disconnect much less frequently, and I could successfully let it run overnight and check it in the morning. [**Edit:** let me clarify that I have not tried this *while closing the browser*. So I can attest to the efficacy of my method *if you leave the browser open*].

I have to say though, that it's been bad for my laptop and it's unacceptable that this is necessary despite what we pay for Colab Pro+. Their product simply does not work as advertised and we have no recourse. If anyone has discovered a better solution (that works) I'm all ears.

Comment: I experimentally reach this solution before. Thank you. Indeed google Colab pro and pro+ is not as good as it is advertised.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that works for me is to make the navigator click with some interval. You can add the following script to the console. It works well with Colab Pro and Pro+ but remember that, if you use the free account, Colab will disconnect you after some hours.

To open the console press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl/command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

```
function Clicking(){
    console.log("Clicking");
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}
setInterval(Clicking,50000)
```